# Ordenar DateTime de uma DataTable

Tags: php, datetime, jquery-datatables, datatable

Estou tendo problemas ao ordenar campo DateTime de uma DataTable, estou retornando registros da minha tabela usuários via server-side. 
O problema está na hora de clicar no label de uma coluna do tipo DateTime, os dados são ordenados como se fossem String e não como DateTime.  Abaixo as imagem de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Usuários</title>
</head>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <h2>Usuários</h2>
    <table id="server-side" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>            
                <th>id.</th>
                <th>Cadastro.</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Sobrenome</th>
                <th>Nível</th>
                <th>Opções</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('#server-side').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "serverSide": true,         
            "aoColumnDefs": [    
            {
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bVisible": false,
        "aTargets": [0]// aqui é a coluna oculta de 'ID

    },
    {
       "aTargets": [5], // o numero 5 é o nº da coluna de AÇÕES/OPÇÕES
       "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) { //aqui é uma funçãozinha para pegar os ids
        return '<a href="view.php?id=' + full[0] + '"  class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Vizualizar</a> '+
        '<a href="edit.php?id=' + full[0] + '"  class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Editar</a> '+
        '<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" data-usuario="' + full[0] + '"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Deletar</a>';
       }
   }
   ],

   language: {
    processing: "Processando...",
   },
   "ajax":{
    url :"server-side.php",
    type: "POST",
    error: function(){
        $("#post_list_processing").css("display","none");
    }
   },
    //ordenando a coluna
    "order": [ 1, "desc"],
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

server-side.php

```
<?php
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'banco';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

// conecta ao banco de dados
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
$con->set_charset("utf8");
// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar
mysqli_select_db($con,$db);

$params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();

$params = $_REQUEST;

$columns = array(
    0 => 'id',
    1 => 'cadastro',
    2 => 'nome', 
    3 => 'sobrenome',
    4 => 'nivel'
    );

$where_condition = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";

if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {
    $where_condition .= " WHERE ";
    $where_condition .= " ( nome LIKE '%".$params['search']['value']."%' ";    
        $where_condition .= " OR sobrenome LIKE '%".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
}

$sql_query = "
SELECT 
id,
date_format(cadastro, '%d/%m/%Y') as cadastro,
nome,
sobrenome,
nivel
FROM usuarios";
$sqlTot .= $sql_query;
$sqlRec .= $sql_query;

if(isset($where_condition) && $where_condition != '') {

    $sqlTot .= $where_condition;
    $sqlRec .= $where_condition;
}

$sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";

$queryTot = mysqli_query($con, $sqlTot) or die("Database Error:". mysqli_error($con));

$totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($queryTot);

$queryRecords = mysqli_query($con, $sqlRec) or die("Error to Get the Post details.");

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
    $data[] = $row;
}   

$json_data = array(
    "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
    "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
    "data"            => $data
    );

echo json_encode($json_data);
?>
```

Segue estrutura da minha tabela "usuarios"

id (int)
cadastro (datetime)
nome (varchar)
sobrenome (varchar)
nivel (int)

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas de realizar a ordenação (*sorting*) do tipo `Date` através da biblioteca DataTables.

De longe, a mais fácil é utilizar o que eles provêm: [DataTable: Sorting plug-ins](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/)

O aconselhado é utilizar o plug-in [Ultimate Date / Time sorting](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment). Você precisará adicionar em conjunto com o plug-in [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

E, antes da chamada do DataTable, adicionar a parametrização:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('dd/mm/YYYY');
    $('#server-side').dataTable({
```

Fontes:

https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment

https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18

Comment: Tentei usar esta função mais ainda está trazendo a data bagunçada

Comment: @SmokeRohden atualize sua pergunta com a nova implementação. Utilize a tag para códigos JavaScript/HTML/CSS e traga alguns dados para que possa ser executado aqui diretamente.